# Dotnet Core - Not able to add a reference to another project that has the base class

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a solution that has a number of projects.

In one project called "JobsLedger.CATALOG.ENTITIES" I have a "Suburb" POCO that I want to inherit from a base class that ins in the project "JobsLedger.ENTITIES.COMMON".

Here is my Suburb class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using JobsLedger.ENTITIES.COMMON.Address;
using JobsLedger.INTERFACES;

namespace JobsLedger.CATALOG.ENTITIES
{
    public class Suburb :  BaseSuburb
    {
        public Suburb()
        {
            Tenants = new List<Tenant>();
            Users = new List<User>();
        }

        public string SuburbName { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }

        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        //// One state to many suburbs
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public State State { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tenant> Tenants { get; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my BaseSuburb class:

```
using JobsLedger.INTERFACES;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace JobsLedger.ENTITIES.COMMON.Address
{
    public class BaseSuburb : IEntityBase
    {
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Locality { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }


        public static BaseSuburb FromCsv(string csvLine)
        {
            if (csvLine == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(csvLine));

            var values = csvLine.Split(',');

            if (values.Length != 7) return null;
            var baseSuburb = new BaseSuburb
            {
                Postcode = Convert.ToInt32(values[0], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                Locality = values[1],
                State = values[2],
                Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(values[3], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(values[4], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
            };

            return baseSuburb;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my csproj for "JobsLedger.CATALOG.ENTITIES":

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.9.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\JobsLedger.DATA.ENTITIES\JobsLedger.DATA.ENTITIES.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\JobsLedger.ENTITIES.COMMON\JobsLedger.ENTITIES.COMMON.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\JobsLedger.INTERFACES\JobsLedger.INTERFACES.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here is my csproj for "JobsLedger.ENTITIES.COMMON".:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\JobsLedger.INTERFACES\JobsLedger.INTERFACES.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Ordinarily this would be a simple reference but the using statement in Suburb -

```
using JobsLedger.ENTITIES.COMMON.Address;
```

is not working. its saying that "ENTITIES" does not exist.

How can I inherit BaseSuburb When its in another project.. should be easy but its not allowing me.

Comment: Have you checked the project reference and ensured is there? also, is the path correct?

Comment: Remove the references and re-add them. Clean and rebuild your solution. Sometimes VS don't behave :)

Comment: Yes.. the project is with all the other projects. The path is correct. The reference is given by Resharper (and Visual Studio as well).. all the others work.. cant figure out why this one isnt.

Comment: Well Im buggered (Aussie) I changed the name and flipped the two words from JobsLedger.ENTITIES.COMMON to JobsLedger.COMMON.ENTITIES and it worked.. why??? it worked though.

Comment: I worked this out. Circular references. Because Suburb was inheriting from BaseSuburb it was not possible to reference back to initial project (from COMMON) because the COMMON was linked to the child project that suburb was in via inheritance. I.E circular due to the inheritance.